# Java Application Running in PASE env on Ibmi - Initial Context Error

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-mq, jndi

I have a basic java application that looks up a data source.
I am new to this, especially when it is running on the IBMi.   ANy thoughts of what/where to look?
I know this is a vague question.
Where would someone "put" the class name the error is mentioning?
I have looked for the declaration of the jndi name on the area of the ibmi that i have access to, but cannot find it....

```
{
       InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/configdb");
}
```

It imediately throws this error:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file: 
 java.naming.factory.initial
```

jndi.properties:

```
# jndi.properties: Defines JNDI properties for standalone Java
java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=file:/Applications/dev/jndi
```

and the dev/jndi/.bindings directory has a whole bunch of stuff in it like this:

```
configdb/RefAddr/35/Type=secondary URL                                    
configdb/ClassName=com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCManagedDataSource
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the context factory in your code like this:

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
    "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");

Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
```